# Center pop up box

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup, popupwindow

I'm at a lost on how i could vertically center the pop up box on the screen.

Anyone have time to take a look at the link. Its based on the datepicker script.

http://jsfiddle.net/bjkaLued/

```
 @media (min-height: 33.875em) {
  .picker__frame {
    overflow: visible;
    top: auto;
    bottom: -100%;
    max-height: 80%;
  }
}
@media (min-height: 40.125em) {
  .picker__frame {
    margin-bottom: 7.5%;
  }
}
/**
 * The wrapper sets the stage to vertically align the box contents.
 */
.picker__wrap {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
@media (min-height: 33.875em) {
  .picker__wrap {
    display: block;
  }
}
/**
 * The box contains all the picker contents.
 */
.picker__box {
  background: #ffffff;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: not hard to find numerous resources on how to center elements

Answer (score 0):

on .picker__box:

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
left: 0;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
background: orange;
```

on .picker__frame:

```
height: 100%
```

Be sure to auto-prefix your transform according to which browsers you need to support.